# Dropdown Subcategories in WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

By default WooCommerce show my categories and subcategories like the image I am posting.

[image]

Is it possible to hide the subcategory Test and only show the Test sub category when you click the main category which is Furniture?

Here is the html code for my page and the CSS I have used:

```css
aside#woocommerce_product_categories-2 ul li:nth-child(4) ul {
    display: none; 
}
    
aside#woocommerce_product_categories-2 ul li:nth-child(4):hover > ul {
    display:block
}
```

```html
<aside id="woocommerce_product_categories-3" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">
     <h5 class="widgettitle">Product Categories</h5>
     <ul class="product-categories">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-28"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/accessories/">accessories</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-29"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/clothes/">clothes</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-30"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/flowers/">flowers</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-38 cat-parent current-cat-parent"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/furniture/">Furniture</a>
               <ul class="children">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-41 current-cat"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/furniture/test/">Test</a></li>
               </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-31"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/home-furnishings/">home furnishings</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-32"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/souvenirs/">souvenirs</a></li>
     </ul>
</aside>
```

It works but I am not sure if this will be a viable option if you have too many categories and subcategories and products...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: no but if i hide it how it will be shown then ? i want to make it as a drop down to its parent category...

Comment: unfortunately i dont know jQuery :/

Comment: yes, i was thinking if its possible with CSS with               ul li:nth-child(4) ul {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109519/discussion-between-christodoulou-andreas-and-loictheaztec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---- *(update - 3)* ----

I have chose **jQuery** and **CSS** to do the job (so you will need to register (enqueu) the js file in your theme).

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* For each category */
  $('ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent').each( function( index, element ){
    /* For each category if there is a subcategory */
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
      /* Adding class 'ok' on rollover mouse event */
       $(this).find('ul.children').addClass('ok');
    }).mouseout(function() {
      /* removing class 'ok' on rollout mouse event */
       $(this).find('ul.children').removeClass('ok');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent > ul.children {
    display: none; 
}
ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent > ul.children.ok {
    display:block; /* (or) display:inline-block; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside id="woocommerce_product_categories-3" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">
     <h5 class="widgettitle">Product Categories</h5>
     <ul class="product-categories">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-28"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/accessories/">accessories</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-29"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/clothes/">clothes</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-30"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/flowers/">flowers</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-38 cat-parent current-cat-parent"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/furniture/">Furniture</a>
               <ul class="children">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-41 current-cat"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/furniture/test/">Test</a></li>
               </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-58 cat-parent current-cat-parent"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/furniture/">Furniture2</a>
               <ul class="children">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-61 current-cat"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/furniture/test/">Test2</a></li>
               </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-31"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/home-furnishings/">home furnishings</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-32"><a href="http://saltandpepper.workshopcy.com/product-category/souvenirs/">souvenirs</a></li>
     </ul>
</aside>
```

I have add another category item (that have a subcategory) to be sure that this script works with multiple items… This script will work for all categories that have subcategories.

After that is possible to animate, with fading transitions, and many more things…

---- *(update 2)* ----

**Registering your script in the functions.php file of your active child theme.**

If you dont have a function.php file in your child theme, copy it from your parent theme. open this file on an editor and delete every code on it (except the first *opening php tag* and if there is a *close php tag* keep it too. 
In between paste this function:

```
// REGISTERING MY JAVASCRIPT FILE IN WORDPRESS HOOK
function registering_my_script_method() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'registering_my_script_method');
```

In your active child theme folder create a `js` and inside create an empty file called `script.js`. Then you will open this `script.js` file and will paste to it, your query code. That'all.

Comment: does it work ? it doesnt drop down the subcategory in Furniture

Comment: its a child theme yes. I think it doesnt work correctly , i cant see the sub category and when i click in Furnitures it redirect me to Test subcategory

Comment: No i wanted a drop down menu for each  Category that got a subgategory . Sorry for my bad english

Comment: how do i register the the js file so i can add it to my wordpress theme code ? Appreciate your help sir

Comment: Thank you so much for your help . I appreciate it , if you want we can share skype and share ideas as well ty again

Comment: I think it doesnt work correctly , the sub categories are open before i hover them . And when iam trying to click on subcategory the dropdown menu is closing .